# Get all unique character of String in sql

Tags: oracle

I have a Table with  column firstName and lastName  as String. Now want to take all unique first char of those  column.my table have thousand of row in that table ,but i just want to have  Is the any string function in SQL to do this?

One more thing I need to find only alphabets no special characters.As my table is big it contains firstname and lastname with special character i need to ignore them

EG:assume my table contains firstname entry as ::jack,tom,riddle,monk,*opeth

In that case my sql should return j,m,r,t

Comment: When you ask a question, be sure to ask everything you need without changing in a few minutes. More: if you use oracle, tag your question for oracle!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(SUBSTR(firstName,1,1)) firstChars
FROM your_table
WHERE LOWER(SUBSTR(firstName,1,1)) IN
 ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j',
  'k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t',
  'u','v','w','x','y','z')
ORDER BY firstChars
```

Comment: this is not returning the list of alphabets as per my requirement and one more filtering I need is that i want only alphabets to take into consideration no special character.The above is not returning the first alphabet of the required column

Comment: @Ashish Sharma: my query returns the first char of _firstName_ column without duplicates. What's wrong with this?

Comment: @Ashish Sharma: query result is exactly the one you requested (_j,m,r,t_)

Comment: following error I  am getting when I use the new query given by you using left.
ora-00904:"LEFT" invalid identifier
00904.00000-"%s" invalid identifier

Comment: @Ashish Sharma: are you using ORACLE?

Comment: This is the query I am using .
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(left(first_name,1)) as firstChars
FROM TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY firstChars

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on 10g or higher the RegEx version of the query requires a lot less typing :)

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(firstName,1,1) 
FROM your_table
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(firstName,'^[[:alpha:]]')
/
```

You may want to apply UPPER() or LOWER() to smooth out mixed case results.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT left(firstName,1) FROM table_name
```

Comment: LEFT() is not an Oracle function.  Your solution also does not address the need to filter out the non-alphabetical characters.

Comment: Ya u r rite..I am using Sql Server 2005 and upper versions